# How to build maven project without version?

Tags: maven

I have a maven project that I want to build without version.

Now, when I build the project using maven, it creates this `commonjerseylib-1.0.war` but I need this `commonjerseylib.war` to be created.

In addition to that, I remove `<version>` tag from `pom.xml` but still Maven is creating with `war` with version 1.0 by default.

My `pom.xml` :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>commonjerseylib</groupId>
<artifactId>commonjerseylib</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<name>commonjerseylib</name>
<!--<version>1.0</version>-->
```

How to build it without version ?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You will always need a version number for a project, however it is possible to change the name of the generated package (JAR, WAR, EAR, etc.) through the `<finalName>` element in the POM.

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

or in older versions of maven:

```
        ...
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        ...
```

By default, the finalName is `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}`, but this can be changed to something else.  This will only affect the name of the package created in the `target` directory; the file name in the local repository and uploaded to remote repositories will always have a version number.

See the [POM reference documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element) for more information.

Comment: That's perfect, Clear and clean!

Comment: As of at least Maven 3.0.3, ${artifactId} is deprecated in favor of ${project.artifactId}.

Comment: @prunge : Thank you for the answer. Do you know any way to do it as it effect to the the file name in the local repository and remote repositories.

Comment: Note that it does not work to override from the command line like `-Dproject.build.finalName=whatever` - if you want to be able to specify the jar's name on the command line, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13877971/587365

Comment: how can i do this in spring boot

Answer (score 14):

in maven war plugin in build, change

```
<warName> ${artifactId} </warName>
```

---

```
<build>
    ..........
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- web.xml is not mandatory since JavaEE 5 -->
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <warName>${artifactId}</warName>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    .............
<build>
```

Answer (score -5):

I fixed it with the below lines of code in the pom

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        ...
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```