# How to build a WAR project in Maven giving a customized name when installed to local repository and deployed to remote repositories

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I know that, I can give a fileName for the WAR file using the build/finalName tag in the pom.xml file.

But this will only affect the name of the package created in the target directory (or a specifically given directory using build/directory). It will not affect to the file name in the local repository and remote repositories and they'll always contains the name with version numbers.

Is there any other way to do this as it will affect to the local repository and remote repositories as well?

References : [how to Build project with maven without version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593473/how-to-build-project-with-maven-without-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the `artifact` in the `repository` is identified by our `pom.xml`, the `group-id` and `artifact-id`. Even we change the `finalName`, there is no any effect, since our `pom.xml` still the same.

Imagine that our `pom.xml` is defined as `some-group:foo`. Then we change the `finalName` to `bar` I've no idea how can we get the `some-group:bar` from the `repository`.

There are no any `pom.xml` which describes about `some-group:bar`.

Comment: That means we have to use it with the artifactid and version number right in those scenarioes? So, final name will be useful for manually deployments but if we are using auto deploy we have to use what is given. I have a main problem in the URL to connect to the WAR.

Comment: AFAIK, the `Glassfish` has a `glassfish-web.xml` and the `weblogic` also has `weblogic.xml` for identifying the `context-root`. I also use this technique to customize my project `URL`. Please refer to your application server configuration guide.

Comment: Yep. That is only one concern Charlee. I didn't ask this question only for that URL issue. I wanted to know whether this naming modification is possible or not with the local/remote repositories. BTW, Thank you very much for the answer and comment. They are very helpful.