# How to give name to the war file?

Tags: spring, maven

I generated a `war` file by executing this command in the root directory of my `Spring` project : `mvn package`

The resulting `war` file is called `hib-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war`

I figured out that the first word `hib` is the project's `artifactId`.

How can I specify a custom name for the generated `war` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a WAR project in Maven giving a customized name when installed to local repository and deployed to remote repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768137/how-to-build-a-war-project-in-maven-giving-a-customized-name-when-installed-to-l)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling maven final name of jar artifact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the variable `finalName` in the build section of the pom.xml in your project:

```
<build>
    <finalName>myname</finalName>
</build>
```

So the war will be renamed to myname.war

Answer (score 3):

You can supply *final name* in build,

```
<build>
    <finalName>my-project</finalName>
</build>
```

It will create `my-project.war` when you *package* the application. By default it will consider following tags to name(`my-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`) the war file,

```
<groupId>com.in</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Other than that you can always rename your war file before deploying it.

Answer (score 1):

**just add following lines inside your pom.xml file** and **It works 100%**

```
       <configuration>                      
             <finalName>customized project name</finalName>
       </configuration>
```

**these lines must put inside the plugin brackets like as:-**

```
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>        
                <configuration>                     
                       <finalName>customized project name</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```