# what class.getResource(...).getFile() returns?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

pom.xml snippet:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>xyzservice</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

result file: xyzservice-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.war

I copied the war file to webapps directory, renamed it to: `xyzservice.war`. Then after extraction by Tomcat, this code:

```
AImpl.class.getResource("/abc/d.pdf").getFile();
```

gave me: `/usr/local/tomcat-8.0.36-8082/webapps/xyzservice-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/abc/d.pdf`   but I am expecting `/usr/local/tomcat-8.0.36-8082/webapps/xyzservice/WEB-INF/classes/abc/d.pdf` without version information. Can anyone explain to me what went wrong & how to fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I copied the war file to webapps directory, renamed it to: xyzservice.war" - and presumably it's then been extracted as /usr/local/tomcat-8.0.36-8082/webapps/xyzservice on the local file system, hence the fil you're getting. That seems entirely reasonable to me...

Comment: The extraction is as expected, but AImpl.class.getResource() did not reflect this, it is still looking for the original name directory structure. Any fix?

Comment: Ah, I see - sorry, misunderstood which way round it was. Just to check, are you certain that it *has* actually been extracted as the file you're expecting?

Comment: yes. It was extracted as the expected: war file name as the root directory name. The real question here is how maven packaging & AImpl.class.getResource(...).getFile() & Tomcat work together.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious from your post that your web application is extracted with name `xyzservice-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT` inside tomcat webapps directory. May be you had renamed the war file, but not the directory inside it.

Please ensure to rename the directory without version i.e `xyzservice` and try again.

If you would like the version to be removed at build time, please refer to the below post and include **warName** tag without version inside **configuration** section of your **maven-war-plugin** in **build** tag.

[how to Build project with maven without version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593473/how-to-build-project-with-maven-without-version)

Comment: does it mean that maven packaged the war file with original war file's name for its directory structure, not the renamed war file? If I have to change the directory name inside war before deployment, that is err-prone. Any better idea?

Comment: Someone voted down my question, so that I could not up vote your answer.

Comment: @Charlie - Your question should read something like **Change WAR name for deployment**. It's possibly a duplicate of the question I referred in my answer.

Comment: The real question here is how maven packaging & AImpl.class.getResource(...).getFile() & Tomcat work together.  Very interesting, I just up voted your answer successfully. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at the initial war file - it is named as `artifactID-version.war` so just renaming the .war file won't help. You'd have to adjust the version in `pom.xml`.

Comment: The real question here is how maven packaging & AImpl.class.getResource(...).getFile() & Tomcat work together

Comment: Maybe it's what it is apparent. Did you try what I mentioned?

Comment: I didn't quite get "adjust the version in pom.xml", I read the answers/comments/links, the version number can be removed by  @beginner 's answer. do you have any comment on "The real question..."?

Comment: Yea that's what I had meant by adjustment. And about your "real question", it is quite clear that `getResource()` contacts Tomcat to get the hosted path and so that means Tomcat has interpreted it using the artifactId and version number.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks alot, @Aakash Verma